# " java regex" match words with numbers and specials caracters

Tags: regex, numbers, character

I have this regex :

```
 "([ ]?[a-zA-Z]{3,})"
```

but when I try match these words :

```
  "sol perro idea \ncaballo\ndo7\ntres\n         tr_es\n8cuatro\ncinco.\n3pesos\n$dollar$\nccc\ncoton\nH7T\n chien@\na-z\n"
```

i get these matchs:

```
 sol
 perro
 idea
caballo
tres
cuatro
cinco
pesos
dollar
ccc
coton
 chien
```

please how i change my regex ???? if i want `8cuatro\n 3pesos\n $dollar$\n and chien@\n` not matched....thanks lot of
bye

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match the leading space, you can omit that from the pattern, and you can also omit the capture group if you want matches only.

You can assert a whitspace boundary to the left, and at the right side a word boundary followed by asserting not `@` to the right.

```
(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b(?!@)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BZCuSd/1)

In Java:

```
String regex = "(?<!\\S)[a-zA-Z]{3,}\\b(?!@)";
String string = "sol perro idea \n"
+ "caballo\n"
+ "do7\n"
+ "tres\n"
+ "         tr_es\n"
+ "8cuatro\n"
+ "cinco.\n"
+ "3pesos\n"
+ "$dollar$\n"
+ "ccc\n"
+ "coton\n"
+ "H7T\n"
+ " chien@\n"
+ "a-z\n";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
sol
perro
idea
caballo
tres
cinco
ccc
coton
```